# Having Issue on Assigning Functions to JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I have an JS Object like

```
var map = {
    prov1: { paper.path("M182.89887,371.5666L18,.... },
    prov2: { paper.path("M182.89887,371.5666L18,.... },
    prov3: { paper.path("M182.89887,371.5666L18,....}
};
```

now I need to assign some function to each of theses properties like

```
 $(map.prov1).hover({
   alert("You Assigned A Task to prov1");
});
```

in a working example it should be like

```
 $(prov1).hover({
   alert("You Assigned A Task to prov1");
});
```

but as you know I can not get access to `$(prov1)` directly and `$(map.prov1)` returns as `[object object]`!

Can you please let me know how to get the `name` and not the `value` of the object to run the function?

Comment: The code you posted is not syntactically valid. I'm surprised you get any output given that the code should not even execute .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to overcomplicate it by using jquery here, when its not needed.

You can simply do...

```
var paper = new Raphael('test', 200, 200);

var attrs = { fill: 'blue' }

var map = {
    prov1: paper.rect(10,10,20,20).attr( attrs ) ,
    prov2: paper.rect(40,40,50,60).attr( attrs ) ,
    prov3: paper.rect(50,60,70,80).attr( attrs )
};

map.prov1.click( function() {  alert('Hi Im prov1') } );
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fms3z394/1/)

If you needed to iterate over the object, you could do something like

```
Object.keys( map ).forEach( function( el ) { 
    map[el].click( function() { alert('Hi, Im ' + el) } ); 
} );
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fms3z394/2/) method with iteration if needed

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this?

```
var map = {
    prov1: function() { return paper.path("M182.89887,371.5666L18,.... ")},
    prov2: function() { return paper.path("M182.89887,371.5666L18,.... ")},
    prov3: function() { return paper.path("M182.89887,371.5666L18,....")}
};

map.prov1();
```

Comment: Hi Aman Thanks for reply but how can you implement a function like `hover` inside `map.prov1();` ?

Comment: hover is just an event that you bind on element. I think your paper.path("M182.89887,371.5666L18,.... ") should be returning element selector. You can use $(map.prov1()).hover() to bind event.

Comment: Ok now I am getting `map.prov()` is not a function error!

Comment: No need for any function returns, as the path is already there really (unless you want it to be element to be created later when calling it).